# mysql return always last insert

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i've a problem with mysql return result. I always obtain the last record row. I explain : I want to get the name of the folder and search the img correspondig.

Here is my code :

```
 <?php
                require( '../core/libs/connexion.php' );

                $sql_mal = 'SELECT * FROM galleries AS G LEFT JOIN activites AS A ON G.id_gallerie=A.fk_id_gallerie WHERE A.fk_id_destination="2"';
                $req_mal = mysqli_query( $connexion, $sql_mal )or die( mysqli_error( $connexion ) );

                global $id_de_activite,$rep_header_activite;

                $sql_activite = 'SELECT nom_type_activite FROM type_activites AS T LEFT JOIN activites AS A ON T.id_type_activite=A.fk_id_type_activite WHERE A.fk_id_destination="2"';

                $req_activite = mysqli_query( $connexion, $sql_activite )or die( mysqli_error( $connexion ) );

                while ( $data_type_activite = mysqli_fetch_array( $req_activite ) ) {

                    $rep_header_activite = trim($data_type_activite['nom_type_activite']);

                }

                while ( $contents_mal = mysqli_fetch_array( $req_mal ) ) {
                    echo '<div class="row">
                                        <div class="col s12 m3">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-image small">


                                                <img src="../00_sources/images/gallerie/activites/cards/'.$rep_header_activite.'/' . $contents_mal[ 'img_thumb' ] . '" alt="' . $contents_mal[ 'img_thumb' ] . '"/>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="card-action">
                                                <span>' . $contents_mal[ 'titre_prin_activite' ] . '</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ';
                    $id_de_activite = $contents_mal['id_activite'];
                    ?>
```

It turns me crazy because the last record is fully showed but the previous one obtain the same name of folder

```
   <img src="../00_sources/images/gallerie/activites/cards/plongee/canoe1521804672.jpeg" alt="canoe1521804672.jpeg">
```

The name of the type of folder is after cards/

Help me pleaaaase i don't know how to resolve this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing your whole `type_activites` request and are only keeping the last row here :

```
 while ( $data_type_activite = mysqli_fetch_array( $req_activite ) ) {

                $rep_header_activite = trim($data_type_activite['nom_type_activite']);

 }
```

Then when you create your img tag, you only use the one stored in `rep_header_activite` which is why it is always the same.

You should only do one sql query and join on the type the first time. It will then be accessible when parsing the sql query. Something like this :

```
SELECT g.*, a.*, t.type_activites 
FROM galleries g 
LEFT JOIN activites a ON g.id_gallerie =a.fk_id_gallerie 
LEFT JOIN  type_activites t ON t.id_type_activite = a.fk_id_type_activite
WHERE a.fk_id_destination="2"
```

You can then remove the first `while` loop and simply access it in the query parsing with the right accessor : `$contents_mal['nom_type_activite']`

Comment: I agree with you, but when i try to join the third table i got a mysql syntax error :    SELECT * FROM galleries AS G LEFT JOIN activites AS A LEFT JOIN type_activites AS T ON G.id_gallerie=A.fk_id_gallerie WHERE A.fk_id_destination="2"

Comment: SELECT * 
     
     FROM galleries AS G
     
     LEFT JOIN activites AS A ON G.id_gallerie=A.fk_id_gallerie
     
     LEFT JOIN type_activites AS T ON T.id_type_activite = A.fk_id_type_activite
     
     WHERE A.fk_id_destination="2" this works !!!

Comment: I was wrong in the syntax of my sql query ! thank you very much !